Streaming data from delegate to function call
I have a 3rd party library that calls a delegate every time there is a buffer of data, and I need to get this buffer into a stream and send the stream to S3.
So I use a FileStream to write to a temporary file:
parser.FileHandler += (buffer, bytes) =>
{
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
};

..and then the file is written to S3:
fileStream.Position = 0;
TransferUtility transferUtility = new(client);
transferUtility.UploadAsync(stream, BucketName, filename).Wait();

MemoryStream is not an option since the files being sent could be very large.
I can't help thinking that there is a better way - how to get the buffered data pieces into S3 directly without using a temporary file or MemoryStream?
But it seems impossible because the library sending the data only provides chunks, not a stream.

You could implement a specialized Stream class based on the parser that allows trasferUtility to read the data from your stream coming from the parser as it arrives.

S3 allows chunked data uploads, might be worth doing a separate upload per file.

Thanks but S3 only allows up to 10,000 parts. I don't know what part size will be sent to me, they could be as small as 1Kb.
